# How can i pass argument to the function using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to display a dialog based on the count variable and i do so like below and it works.

```
function Parent() {
    const DialogRequest = useDialogRequest();
    const onAdd = () => {
        const count = 2;
        if (count < 1) {
            DialogRequest(true);
        }
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <button onClick={onAdd}>Add</button>
        );
    }
}

function Dialog(onHide) { 
    return( 
        {showDialog? 
            <Wrapper> 
                <Body>
                    <button> add</button>
                </Body>
            </Wrapper>
         : null }
    );
}

const dialogRequestContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({});

export const DialogRequestProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [showDialog,setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);

    const onHide = () => {
        setDialogOpen(false);
    };
    const setDialogOpen = (open: boolean) => {
        if (open) {
            const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('dialog');
            if (sessionDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
                setShowDialog(open);
                sessionStorage.setItem('dialog', 'closed');
            }
        } else {
            setShowDialog(open);
        }
    };
    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{ setDialogOpen }}
        >
            {children}
            <Dialog onHide={onHide}
                showDialog={showDialog}
            />
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
};



export function useDialogRequest() {
    const dialogRequestContext = React.useContext(
        dialogRequestContext
    );


    return function DialogRequest(open: boolean) {
        if (dialogRequestContext &&
            dialogRequestContext.setDialogOpen
        ) {
            dialogRequestContext.setDialogOpen(open);
        }
    };
}
```

Now i want to pass the count to DialogRequest so that count can be used within Dialog component. i have tried below,

```
function Parent() {
    const DialogRequest = useDialogRequest();
    const onAdd = () => {
        const count = 2;
        if (count < 0) {
            DialogRequest(true, count); //passing count here
        }
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <button onClick={onAdd}>Add</button>
        );
    }
}
```

But not sure how to modify the DialogRequestComponent and pass it to Dialog component from there. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with `count`?

Comment: updated question. if count < 0 then  want to display add button or not.